# Page is greyed out when search button is pressed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a app in Xamarin forms and I'm having a problem..

I've got a search page with a search bar and when the search button is pressed it slightly grey out the page, this only happens on the android version.

[Here's what it looks like normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfAn3.png)

[And here's what it looks like when search button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSYAi.png)

The problem is that if I don't delete the search text manually the whole app is slightly greyed out, until I go back to the search page and click the search bar, then the grey tint disappears.

Have someone else experienced this?

As mentioned, this only happens on android, not iOS.

I'm using Xamarin forms 4.3 if that helps.

Comment: I write a demo, run it in the Android emulator, I met this issue like you, But I test my code in the Android Device(Google Pixel and Huawei), it running normally, you can test it.

Comment: I've tested it on a google pixel emulator, same results... thank you for your answer though!

Comment: Oh or did you mean that you tested it on a physical device? Because I haven't tested it on a real device, only on a emulator.

Comment: Yes, I test it on a real device, it is running normally.

Comment: Okey, thank you for your answer, I'm going to try this!

Comment: Ok, waitting for your update.

Comment: It's working! Thank you!

Comment: Can I post above comment to answer? Then you accept it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Yes of course!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a test demo, run it in the Android emulator, I met same issue.

This is a GIF in emulator about this issue.

[image]

But I test my code in the Android Device(Google Pixel and Huawei), they are running normally without this issue.

This is a GIF in Google Pixel.

[image]

**Conclusion:**
We can ignore this issue.

Comment: @JonathanK  You can click the "✔" in the upper right corner of this answer to accept this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your time!